# Condition for differential inequality

Tags: functions, inequality

Let $f(x) = \frac{e^{ - ax}}{1 + {e^{bx}}}$, where $x>0$, $a$ and $b$ are positive constants. Find the condition of $a$ and $b$ so that
$$
( - 1)^nf^{(n)}(x) \ge 0
$$
with all $x>0$ and $n$, where $f^{(n)}(x) $ is the $n$th derivative of $f(x)$.

Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

You should use "\dfrac" instead of "\frac" when you have such fractions, it'll make your equations easier to read ;)

You should first try to differentiate your function and try to find a relationship between $f'$ and $f$ and find a expression for $f^{(n)}$

To do this, I would advise you to:

1. write $f=\dfrac{u}{v}$
2. express $u'$ with $u$ and $v'$ with $v$
3. replace those in $f'$
4. find a pattern

I didn't do any computation, so it might not be the right way to go but I think it's worth trying.